# How can I use 2 motors to increase rpm on one wheel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I want to add power of both motors in such a way that it increases the RPM on a wheel, to be used in a tricycle.

Comment: You haven't mentioned why you think that just attaching both motors together isn't an option. This is the simplest way to accomplish what you are looking for, so you should explain why this isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should simply get a bigger motor.  Two motors adding to the same power will have more overhead.

If you must use two motors, then just connect them mechanically.  There is nothing special you need to do to have two identical DC electric motors add their torques to the same shaft.  The no-load maximum speed will still be the same, but the torque at all lower speeds will be doubled compared to a single motor.

This assumes you aren't trying to run each motor independently but synchronously or phase controlled.  They can be brushless DC, but controlled at a higher level as if they were brushed DC motors.

Answer (score 0):

basically to use energy of both motors at once you will need to store that energy somewhere. here comes flywheel.

I drew rough diagram how the arrangement can look like in figure below.

BLUE - motors

GREEN - worm and worm wheel\gear

YELLOW - flywheel shaft

LIGHT RED - flywheel

RED - output shaft.

[image]

though this mechanism can be a challenge to use in a tricycle , this principle of storing mechanical energy from multiple sources into flywheel and using all of it in single output shaft is used for ages in the IC engine.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Why does "use" imply "storage"? And what's the point of putting a flywheel on a worm-driven shaft? Flywheels are much more effective if they're placed on the *higher-speed* shafts in a system.